# PadFone X using MHL?

Tags: mhl

What is the PadFone X using to output audio/ video to the tablet dock? Is it propriety firmware, MHL, or what? I'd like to hardwire to a monitor/TV. It would also be nice to be able to wire back to the dock when an OTG hub is connected to the phone. Would this require a hacked cable?

Comment: I've since learned this is a slimport. I got a slimport cable that breaks out to HDMI and USB for power. Works awesome! It doesn't appear though that a hub would work though.

Answer (score 0):

Slimport is the technology used here.